# What is the concept of linux stores the output to a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

Can anyone help me to understand the concept of how the Linux stores its terminal output to a variable?

```
files=`ls`
echo $files
a.txt
b.txt
```

I want to know-how Linux stores this to a variable. I mean whatever the "ls" output to stdout will redirect to the variable "files" or any operation will takes place?

Comment: Has nothing to do with linux, or any specific OS, but how sh/bash/etc. works.

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002 and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Answer (score 0):

The terminal isn't really relevant. Your question seems to imply that all commands write directly to the terminal, then command substitution somehow "copies" what was written to a variable.

It's the other way around: commands write to *standard output*, which is some file the command *receives* from whoever starts the command. Standard output for an interactive shell is the terminal, but the command substitution overrides that, causing the shell to capture the output in memory, then using that output to set the value of the variable.